# How can I get the sum of the digits in the char array (sum from 2 to 4)? I tried the code below, but it does not give the required answer

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void){

    char a[11]= "EN21396304";
    char*ptr1;

    ptr1 = a;
    ptr1 = (ptr1+2);

    char i;
    char sum = 0;

    for(i=0; i<=8; i++){
        sum = sum + *(ptr1+i);
    }  

    printf("Sum of the digits in the array = %d\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to add add the ascii values or the decimal values? I assume the latter. In which case you need: `sum = sum + ptr[i] - '0';`. That is, you need to rebase each ascii character to convert it to the corresponding int value. So `'0'` ascii becomes `0` int, `'1'` becomes `1`, etc. Also, using array syntax is usually more understandable.

Comment: Think about assigning to `ptr1` in two sequential statements. What did the first assignment accomplish?

Comment: Also, please note that explicitly stating the number of characters in a string literal assignment like that is just opening yourself up to the possibility of errors. Let the compiler do that for you with `char a[] = "EN21396304";`

Comment: @kaylum Thank you.  It solved the issue. Could you please explain a little more about the part where we subtract '0'? How does it help with the conversion process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding ASCII values. You also don't need a separate pointer (`ptr1`). What you want is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    char a[] = "EN21396304";
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 2; a[i]; i++) {
        sum += (a[i] - '0');
    }  

    printf("Sum of the digits in the array = %d\n", sum);
}
```

Note that `sum` should be an `int`, because `int` is the most natural and efficient type for the platform and compiler.

Comment: Thank you. It solved the issue. Could you please explain a little more about the part where we subtract the '0'? How does it help with the process of converting ASCII into decimal values?

Comment: Sure. The decimal digit characters are represented by ASCII character code 48 ('0') to 57 ('9'), so if we subtract '0' (48) from the ASCII code for the digit, we get the actual value of the digit.

Answer (score 0):

To perform such type of operations you don't need to use pointers.

#### Process-

- loop through the entire array
- check for every character that `isdigit()`
- if yes then convert that character to integer and just add to the `sum`

This can be simply achieved by the following code and it works for every strings-

```c
#include <ctype.h>  // it's for isdigit()
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void){
    char arr[]= "EN21396304";
    int i=0, sum=0;
    // Looping through char array
    while( arr[i] != '\0'){
        
        // checking it is digit or not if it is then add to the sum after converting it to int
        if (isdigit(arr[i]) != 0)
            sum += arr[i] - '0';
        i++;
    }  
    printf("Sum of the digits in the array = %d\n", sum);
}
```

You need to use `#include <ctype.h>` as header file because we want to use `isdigit()` function.